# Decoding invalid URLs as nil

Tags: swift, url, codable

*Before you answer:*

I'm aware:

- That an empty string is an invalid `URL`
- That I could write a custom decoder for `Employee`
- That I could declare `url` as a `String`

What I'm looking for is a better solution for decoding the optional `URL` itself. I'm hoping there's some `Codable` magic I'm missing!

---

So, I have JSON such as

```
let json = Data("""
                {
                    "name": "Fred",
                    "url": ""
                }
                """.utf8)
```

and a corresponding object that contains an optional URL…

```
struct Employee: Decodable {
    let name: String
    let url: URL?
}
```

As `url` in the JSON is invalid, I'd like it to decode as `nil`, rather than throwing an error.

Trying the following doesn't work (it doesn't get called)…

```
extension Optional where Wrapped == URL {
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        do {
            self = try container.decode(URL.self)
        } catch {
            self = nil
        }
    }
}
```

In the past I've used…

```
struct FailableDecodable<T: Decodable>: Deodable {

    let wrapped: T?

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        do {
            self.wrapped = try container.decode(T.self)
        } catch {
            print("Error decoding failable object: \(error)")
            self.wrapped = nil
        }
    }
}

struct Employee: Decodable {
    let name: String
    let url: FailableDecodable<URL>?
}
```

but this requires me to continually refer to `url.wrapped`.

Is there a better solution?

Comment: the build in decoder fails if it's not a valid url , you have to override init decoder

Comment: How often is URL called? If only once then you can consider setting the type in your model to String, and after the JSON serialization has happened convert it to an URL?.

Comment: @Sh_Khan, I'm aware of that, thank you. I'd like a solution that doesn't require me to write a custom decoder for every object that contains an optional URL. Hence why I was trying to override the `Optional where Wrapped == URL`, but without success, and the `FailableDecodable` (which requires use of `.wrapped` whenever the URL is used)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you are using Swift 5.1, you can use `@propertyWrapper`:

```swift
let json = """
{
    "name": "Fred",
    "url": ""
}
""".data(using: .utf8)!


@propertyWrapper
struct FailableDecodable<Wrapped: Decodable>: Decodable {
    var wrappedValue: Wrapped?

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        wrappedValue = try? container.decode(Wrapped.self)
    }
}

struct Employee: Decodable {
    let name: String

    @FailableDecodable
    private(set) var url: URL?
}

let employee = try! JSONDecoder().decode(Employee.self, from: json)
employee.url // nil
```

**Edit — Codable version**

If you need the top level struct to be `Encodable` as well you can use `Codable` conformance to the property wrapper.

```swift
@propertyWrapper
struct FailableDecodable<Wrapped: Codable>: Codable {
    var wrappedValue: Wrapped?

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        wrappedValue = try? container.decode(Wrapped.self)
    }
    
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
        try container.encode(wrappedValue)
    }
}
```

If `url` is `nil` this will output a JSON with `url: null`

```json
{"name":"Fred","url":null}
```

If you wish to don't output the `url` property when `nil` you will need to implement a custom encoding (with `encode(to:)`) in `Employee` (which would mitigate the benefit of using a property wrapper).

**Note:** Using the default implementation of `encode(to:)` (not implementing it) works, but output an empty object when `url` is `nil`:

```json
{"name":"Fred","url":{}}
```

Comment: Give that man a cigar! That is exactly the answer I was looking for. I've added a pre-check for `nil` to my `init` method as follows… `if container.decodeNil() {
            wrappedValue = nil
            return
        }`. This prevents the `try?` breaking on swift errors each time.

Comment: This is very cool! how would you attack it if you need Encodable as well?

Comment: @iCediCe I edited my answer with a `Codable` version

Comment: This fails when `url` key is missing from json. So decoding will fail for this: 
`let json = """
{
    "name": "Fred"
}
"""` And sorry, I don't have a solution.

Answer (score 2):

If you get `Return from initializer without initializing all stored properties` warning for your `Codable` struct initializer that contains `@FailableDecodable` below will resolve it.

```
@propertyWrapper
struct FailableDecodable<Wrapped: Codable>: Codable {
    
    var wrappedValue: Wrapped?
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        wrappedValue = try? container.decode(Wrapped.self)
    }
    
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
        try container.encode(wrappedValue)
    }
    
    init() {
        self.wrappedValue = nil
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the excellent `@propertyWrapper` solution above, I wanted to include a fix for the failure when the `url` key is not present in the JSON.

It never gets to the `init(from decoder: Decoder)` method as the key doesn't exist, so we need to add an extension onto `KeyedCodingContainer` to handle this case.

```swift
extension KeyedDecodingContainer {
  func decode<Wrapped: Codable>(_ type: FailableDecodable<Wrapped>.Type, forKey key: K) throws -> FailableDecodable<Wrapped> {
    if let value = try self.decodeIfPresent(type, forKey: key) {
      return value
    }

    return FailableDecodable(wrappedValue: nil)
  }
}
```

I also needed to add another initializer manually to `FailableDecodable` to make this compile.

```
init(wrappedValue: Wrapped?) {
  self.wrappedValue = wrappedValue
}
```

I found that with these changes, The answer from @rraphael above was perfect!